# Jquery click event and if else statement

Tags: jquery

I just don't understand jquery. I know how if else statement works but here is something wrong.

```
$('.box').each( function() {
    alert ( ($this).find('input').attr('id') ) //here i see that click is 
                                            //made two times for that same element
                                            //and i dont know why
    $(this).click( function() {
        if ( $(this).find('label').attr('class') == 'active' ) {
           $(this).find('label').removeClass('active');
           $(this).find('input').prop("checked", false);
        }else{

          alert('shit');
          $label.find('input').prop("checked", true);
          $label.find('label').addClass('active')
        }
    }
}
});
```

Can somebody tell my why when i click on $(this) it first make "else" statement and then "if" statement?

MY HTML:

```
<% Profile.options('gender').each do |key, value| %>

<li class='box'><%= check_box_tag "search[gender][#{value}]", value, false%>
<%= label_tag "search[gender][#{value}]", key %></li>

<% end %>
```

So when i click on label i want to have "active" class. When i second click on that label, i want to remove "active" class from it.

ANSWER:

I must change <%= label_tag "search[gender][#{value}] to "search[gender][#{value}]_#{value}" - because when label have that same ID as input, it make two times click event.

Comment: Given that this code wouldn't compile and that we don't see the HTML, it's hard to answer. Please look at http://sscce.org

Comment: Difficult to know without seeing your html

Comment: `$('#box').each()` is a red flag, element `id`s must be unique.

Comment: `alert($(this).find('input').attr('id'));` instead of `alert($this).find('input').attr('id')`

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Your label doesn't have `active` class on the first click. That's why it goes to `else`. Then when you click again it executes `if` because it has been added on `else` before.

Comment: i do not click second time - and that is the problem.

Comment: Why do you think it goes to both branches? Are you sure you aren't just getting an error because `$label` is undefined?

Comment: I know because alert ( ($this).find('input').attr('id') ) throw me two times that same ID.

Comment: ...That's outside the click handler. I think you need to create a reproducible example at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Ah, I bet this snippet is being executed twice for some reason, binding two click handlers, so the toggle actually happens twice and you end up back where you started.

Comment: Ok now i see that when i remove "label" with that same ID as input - click is made only once.

Answer (score 0):

The `.each()` allows you to loop through a collection of elements. An ID is not a collection, it is (supposed to be!) a single element. A class may be a collection of elements.

The line:

```
alert($this).find('input').attr('id')
```

Should be:

```
alert( $(this).find('input').attr('id') );
```

The missing parentheses will throw everything else off.  Fix that one first.

If you show us your HTML, and tell us a little more about what you are trying to do, we can help further.

Comment: i just write with bug in here, in my script alert is ok. When i change #box to .box - doesnt change anything.

Comment: How many #box elements do you have? If only one, then you don't need the `.each()` method. If you have more than one #box element, then you should rename them all to `class="box"` instead of `id="box"` -- IDs must be *unique*.

Comment: Please ensure that your code in the above question is EXACTLY what you have in your real code, character-for-character.